# Gradle: Adding version to filename for ivy resolved dependencies

Tags: gradle, version, filenames, rename, ivy

I'm using a local ivy repository as following:

```
repositories {
ivy {
    url  = "${project.rootDir.absolutePath}/../ivy/ivy-repositories/shared/"
    layout "pattern", {
        artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext]"
        ivy "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"
    }
    resolve.dynamicMode = true
}
}
```

I'm using the distribution plugin and set content with:

```
distributions {
main {
    contents {
          into ('libs')
        { from {
                project(':x-impl').configurations.runtime
            } }
 }
 }
```

My problem is that the filename of the resolved artifacts (jars) lacks the version. Ie 'commons-codec.jar' instead of 'commons-codec-1.6.jar'. Both on my Eclipse classpath and in the distribution.

Is there any way i can let the version be part of the filename? I can not (easily) change the layout/pattern of the local ivy repository.

Thins question was originally asked at the gradle community but received no answers:
http://gsfn.us/t/4iiml

Thanks, 
Andreas

Comment: It will take effort. You could perhaps iterate over the artifacts (check out the `Configuration#incoming` and `Configuration#resolvedConfiguration` APIs in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html)), add the corresponding files to `from`, and rename the files according to the artifact info (perhaps with `CopySpec#rename`, search [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) for "rename"). Or perhaps you could use a single `from` and `rename` and inside the latter, look up the corresponding artifact and version.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Seems we are a bit stuck then using a "non defacto (but normalized) standard pattern" for our ivy repo. In ivy(+ant) we could do first a filesystem resolve pattern and later a retrive pattern to go from eg. {artifact}.{ext} to {artifact}-{rev}-{type}.{ext}. Apart from the above problem we also have the problem that src, javadoc and bin type artifacts get the same filename in wars and eclipse classpaths. Do you have any other suggestion for us? Would a feature request to Gradle be appropriate and likely to be impl (are you involved in G?)?

Comment: Older discussion at http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Standard-patterns-for-ivy-repositories-td4793222.html